# Date stored as string and unable to apply DateValue or CDate

Tags: string, date, ms-access

Date stored as a string in Access. I'm not able to apply the suggested solutions such as DateValue and Cdate. I tried to reformat to add a delimiter but it gives me a mismatched error. The data is stored as such: "201704100705"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast it to a datetime value first:

```
DateSerial(Left(MyField,4), Mid(MyField,5,2), Mid(MyField,8,2)) + TimeSerial(Mid(MyField,10,2), Right(MyField,2))
```

After that, you can use the usual date/time functions.

Comment: Thanks. I am a complete newbie to the sql world and so I typed the following and am running into errors. I believe that I did not place the expression in the correct place:

SELECT XA_WETHR.XactStamp, XA_WETHR.Datestamp
Where DateSerial(Left(MyField,5,2), Mid(MyField,8,2)) + TimeSerial(Mid(MyField,10,2), Right(MyField,2))
FROM XA_WETHR;

Comment: Firstly, you need to replace `MyField` with your field name. Secondly, you have a misplaced `WHERE`: `WHERE` comes after `FROM`.

Comment: Thank you. I've made adjustments and simplified the expression to see if it might work better but I am not getting the desired result:

SELECT XA_WETHR.XactStamp
FROM XA_WETHR
WHERE Format(DateSerial(Left(XactStamp,4), Mid(XactStamp,5,2), Mid(XactStamp,8,2)));

The result is: 20050802070000

Comment: Why is it in the `WHERE` clause? Just do `SELECT XA_WETHR.XactStamp, DateSerial(Left(XactStamp,4), Mid(XactStamp,5,2), Mid(XactStamp,8,2)) FROM XA_WETHR;`